# How to efficiently update values without a primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently facing an issue with designing a database table and updating/inserting values into it.
The table is used to collect and aggregate statistics that are identified by:

- the source
- the user
- the statistic
- an optional material (e.g. item type)
- an optional entity (e.g. animal)

My main issue is, that my proposed primary key is too large because of `VARCHAR`s that are used to identify a statistic.

My current table is created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Statistics` (
 `server_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `player_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
 `statistic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` bigint(20) NOT NULL)
```

In particular, the `server_id` is configurable, the `player_id` is a UUID, `statistic` is the representation of an enumeration that may change, `material` and `entity` likewise. The `value` is then aggregated using `SUM()` to calculate the overall statistic.

So far it works but I have to use `DELETE` AND `INSERT` statements whenever I want to update a value, because I have no primary key and I can't figure out how to create such a primary key in the constraints of MySQL.

My main question is: How can I efficiently update values in this table and insert them when they are not currently present without resorting to deleting all the rows and inserting new ones?

The main issue seems to be the restriction MySQL puts on the primary key. I don't think adding an `id` column would solve this.

Comment: Whats the problem in writing an update query? It may contain any combination of `WHERE` conditions, and if you know which conditions to put into the `DELETE` query, these are the same to use for your `UPDATE` query

Comment: @NicoHaase the main problem was a primary key. But I solved this issue already.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an auto-incremented id:

```
CREATE TABLE `Statistics` (
 statistis_id int auto_increment primary key,
 `server_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `player_id` binary(16) NOT NULL,
 `statistic` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `material` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `entity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `value` bigint(20) NOT NULL
);
```

Voila!  A primary key.  But you probably want an index.  One that comes to mind:

```
create index idx_statistics_server_player_statistic on statistics(server_id, player_id, statistic)`
```

Depending on what your code looks like, you might want additional or different keys in the index, or more than one index.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below hope it will solve your problem :-
- First use a variable let suppose "detailed" as money with your table.
- in your project when you use insert statement then before using statement get the maximum of detailed (SELECT MAX(detailed)+1 as maxid FROM TABLE_NAME( and use this as use number which will help you to FETCH,DELETE the record.
-you can also update with this also BUT during update MAXIMUM of detailed is not required.

Hope you understand this and it will help you .

Answer (score 0):

I have dug a bit more through the internet and optimized my code a lot.

I asked this question because of bad performance, which I assumed was because of the `DELETE` and `INSERT` statements following each other.

I was thinking that I could try to reduce the load by doing `INSERT IGNORE` statements followed by `UPDATE` statements or `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements. But they require keys to be useful which I haven't had access to, because of constraints in MySQL.

**I have fixed the performance issues though:**

By reducing the amount of statements generated asynchronously (I know JDBC is blocking but it worked, it just blocked thousand of threads) and **disabling auto-commit**, I was able to improve the performance by **600** times (from 60 seconds down to 0.1 seconds).

Next steps are to improve the connection string and gaining even more performance.